# How to create a table-structured content type?

Tags: nodes

I am creating a content type which needs to be in table format. The table structure looks like below:

```
Main title for the table 1:
........................................................
First row with text content     corresponding image here
Second row with text content    corresponding image here

                             Main title for the table 2:
........................................................
corresponding image here    First row with text content
corresponding image here    Second row with text content

Main title for the table 3:
........................................................
First row with text content     corresponding image here
Second row with text content    corresponding image here
```

When end user want to add new text and image, they should be able to add this content type and a new row should be added underneath. What is the nest way to do this? I am able to create content type and show them on my nodes. I just want to show the content type in table format. Need ideas to get this done! Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like Paragraphs to me.

Comment: Check this! https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs